# How to check free space on Unix using script

Tags: unix

How can I check for free space of a list of specific folders on Unix.

Details:
I have a list of name of directories, and I need to check if the space utilization of those folders have exceeded a given limit.

Comment: Try `man df` and/or `man du`

Comment: Thanks Mark! I used "du -sk *" from the folder where i needed to list the size utilization of folders and it gave me result what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very usually we need to search directories which has physical files eating up spaces. So, we start looking sizes of directories occupying most space, and drill down to junk/unwanted dir/file.
The more better thing is to get dir list in order of occupying space, highest at top. Command to get top 10 of this is:-

```
du -a <path> | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, you can also do:

```
du -ks dirA dirB
10240   dirA
20480   dirB
```

Or this:

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=100
for f in dirA dirB
do
   echo Checking $f...
   size=$(du -ks "$f" | awk '{print $1}')
   if [ $size -gt $limit ]; then
      echo $f is $size kB - exceeding limit of $limit kB
   fi
done
```

**Output**

```
Checking dirA...
dirA is 10240 kB - exceeding limit of 100 kB
Checking dirB...
dirB is 20480 kB - exceeding limit of 100 kB
```